# ExceptionMapper entity seems to get wrapped by Quarkus

Tags: java, jax-rs, quarkus

In Quarkus, it seem that the entity returned by an exception mapper get wrapped in another entity.

Give an JAX-RS exception mapper like:

```
@Provider
public class WebhookExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<WebhookException> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(final WebhookException e) {
        return Response.status(e.getError().getCode().getStatus())
                .entity(Entity.entity(e.getError(), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .build();
    }
}
```

I get the following error response:

```
{
  "entity": {
    "code": "SOME_ERROR_CODE",
    "msg": "Error message"
  },
  "variant": {
    "language": null,
    "mediaType": {
      "type": "application",
      "subtype": "json",
      "parameters": {},
      "wildcardType": false,
      "wildcardSubtype": false
    },
    "encoding": null,
    "languageString": null
  },
  "annotations": [],
  "mediaType": {
    "type": "application",
    "subtype": "json",
    "parameters": {},
    "wildcardType": false,
    "wildcardSubtype": false
  },
  "language": null,
  "encoding": null
}
```

I would like the following to be returned:

```
{
  "code": "SOME_ERROR_CODE",
  "msg": "Error message"

}
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As is seen by looking at the package name, the [javax.ws.rs.client.Entity](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/client/Entity.html) class is only meant to be used on the client side. On the server side, you don't need to use it. What you are actually seeing is the `Entity` object being serialized, not the error.

If you want to set the type, just use the `type()` method on the [`Response.ResponseBuilder`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.ResponseBuilder.html) (that you get back from calling `Response.status()`). And to set the body just use the `entity()` method.

```
return Response.status(e.getError().getCode().getStatus())
        .entity(e.getError())
        .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .build();
```

Comment: Thanks, I totally missed that